# Why is this command need to for PIP "py -m pip install <package-name>

Tags: python, windows, pip

Why is this command need to for PIP "py -m pip install

I tried multiple times from visual studio but the only method to get it to work was from the terminal/cmd

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: `python -m <module> <cmd>` denotes that you are using an installed module, not a script. It will search `site-packages` for the interpreter being used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few components to this command:

- `py.exe` is a global command on Windows (when installed) that will automatically select the latest version of Python. It is like using `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe` but without having to type it every time.
- `-m pip` is an option for Python that essentially means "find and run `pip` for me"
- `install …` are options for pip

Because the first step is running an executable, you need to do that from a program that allows you to run executables. Typically, this would be Explorer, the Start Menu, or Command Prompt/Powershell. If you are already using Visual Studio, you will need to switch to one of these programs to run *this particular* command.

However, Visual Studio itself offers ways to install Python packages without using this particular command. There is full information in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/python), but if you selected "Python" when installing it then you will have a Python Environments window (look under the View / Other Windows menu).

[image: Python Environments window]

That dropdown that currently says "Overview" in the screenshot also has a "Packages" view. If you look at that, it handles the first two components of your original command for you - it will find the right version of Python and be able to run `pip`. There is a text box where you can type the name of packages to install.

Under the hood, all Visual Studio is really doing is running `python -m pip install <whatever you type>`, so it isn't doing anything special compared to the `py` command. But it is an alternative to switching to a terminal if you want to stay in VS.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I was getting an error " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wxPython (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for wxPython" when trying to do this from VS2015.  This is why I ended up needing to run it from the shell. I still have not figured out how to get pip to work from VS.